# Creating graph from sequential patterns and finding paths between nodes - neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, sequential, edges

I would like to create a graph model that captures the following sequential patterns and return unique paths between specific nodes:

Sequential Patterns

| Pattern ID | Sequential Pattern |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `A8-->A9` |
| 2 | `A8-->S8-->A9` |
| 3 | `A8-->A9-->S9` |
| 4 | `A8-->S6-->S8` |
| 5 | `S8-->A8-->A9` |
| 6 | `A8-->S8-->S9` |

Edges of Graph Model

| Edge ID | From Node | To Node | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A8 | A9 | `-Transition->` |
| 2 | A8 | S8 | `-Transition->` |
| 3 | S8 | A9 | `-Transition->` |
| 4 | A9 | S9 | `-Transition->` |
| 5 | A8 | S6 | `-Transition->` |
| 6 | S6 | S8 | `-Transition->` |
| 7 | S8 | A8 | `-Transition->` |
| 8 | S8 | S9 | `-Transition->` |

The desired output of unique paths starting at A8 and ending at A9:

| Path ID | Unique Path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `A8-->A9` |
| 2 | `A8-->S8-->A9` |

I have tried the following:

```
MATCH (a: node{name:'A8'})
MATCH (b:node{name:'A9'})
CALL apoc.algo.allSimplePaths(a,b,'Transition>',3)
YIELD path
RETURN reduce(s="",n in nodes(path) | s+(CASE WHEN s="" THEN "" ELSE "-->" END) +n.name) as string
```

I get the following output:

| string |
| --- |
| `A8-->A9` |
| `A8-->S8-->A9` |
| `A8-->S6-->S8-->A9 *` |
| `A8-->S9-->A9 *` |
| `A8-->S8-->S9-->A9 *` |
| `A8-->S6-->S9--A9 *` |

Any suggestions on how I can produce an output that excludes the last 4 paths (marked with *)?

Comment: Your query has a typo: "NAME" should be "name". Even with that fixed, your results are impossible given your stated relationships (edges). There is not supposed to be a `A8-->S9` relationship, for example. So, you need to fix your question to be consistent. Also, what exactly do you mean by a "unique" path? All the results you provided do seem to be unique.

Comment: Thank you for the response, @cyberam. I fixed the query and the relationships table. In the original dataset, there are only two paths between A8 and A9 (i.e., A8-->A9 & A8-->S8-->A9). How do I get only these two paths from the graph I generated from the nodes and the relationships between them?

Comment: Your updated query now correctly returns just the 2 expected paths from your updated relationships. (And the rest of your question is no longer consistent.